# I get 'Error: Input is not defined' when trying to pass parameter to child component

Tags: angular

I'm practicing angular2 and i'm really new in it.
I built 2 components - a parent and its child.
When i'm trying to pass to some parameter from the parent component to its child, I get 'Error: Input is not defined'. Could someone help me with it, because I'm not able to see what i'm doing wrong.

```
export class SquadComponent{
  @Input() selectedteam;
}
```

[my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CpnpytPlLl3iWok8mhm)

Answer (score 7):

Just import `Input` before use of it like this

```
import { Component, Input } from 'angular2/core'
```

Working example http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXI8FwfYvrcAkTxtUPNy?p=preview

## Update

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'
```

Comment: well I guess I'll have to get used to the idea of importing everything... Thanx

Comment: the same is true for 'Output'?